# Pin/Parent Vertex of OBJ1 to Vertex of OBJ2

Tags: animation, rigging, vertices, parent

Is it possible to parent/pin the vertice of one object to the vertice of another object? Essentially parenting, but on a vertice basis instead.

For example, two cubes have a corner overlap, those two vertices are pinned together. If I move the "parent" cube, the "child" cube's corner will distort, following.

This may seem like an odd question, because you can accomplish the effect with bones, but for my application, that would produce a ton of bones to manage, along with weight painting and such.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you select two objects, you can hook a vertex from the last selected (after entering edit mode) to "selected object", ie to the last object selected (to its origin). You could move the origin to a vertex in this last object... but it's not ideal

Or, you can do this, perhaps better:

1. from the object 1 (the one that has the vertex you wish to pin to), select the vertex and move the 3d cursor there (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > "cursor to selected")
2. then add a new empty, and move it to the 3d cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > "selected to cursor")
3. then parent the empty to the object 1
4. then selected the empty and then the object 2 with the vertex you wish to pin to the object 1 vertex
5. enter edit mode, and select the object 2 vertex to be pinned
6. from mesh > vertices > hooks > "hook to selected object" (the empty)

[image]

if I got it well...

Comment: Steps 1, 2 and  3 are easier by selecting a vertex and doing **hook to new object** that will create an empty where the vertex is and hook it to the the vertex.

Comment: I know what that does, but "if I got well" what OP asks, to get what he wishes, ie to "pin" a vertex from object 2 to a vertex of object 1, I think he needs to do as I wrote above. Maybe I got it wrong though... your alternative to 1,2,3 creates the empty but the vertex is hooked to it, not viceversa... so the other object could be pinned to ? the empty ? so, not to the other vertex, as I believe he asked... the empty must "stay" where the obj 1 vertex is. SO, hooking the empty, is exactly like hooking the parented obj vertex vertex lying there.

Comment: Thanks OP & @cegaton - This will help me cut down on the number of bones I need to get my desired effect.

Comment: @Jason Ford good! btw, OP = original poster, ie, you :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Thread